# Android calendar data storage & transfer

Tags: storage, calendar

How can I transfer ALL stored calendar data (android, HUAWEI MATE 9 app) to Samsung galaxy note 8? Transfer has  been possible only for last year's data (2017). Not all previous years' data in calendar could be moved to new phone. I have used the "Smart Switch" app on both phones.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use an app called "Copy my Data" on both phones to move calendar data.